# Overload operator < , == for a fraction type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the operator< in C++. So far, I only managed to do the +,-,*,/. And I've come out with this code:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator/(Fraction &second)
{ 
    int n1 = getNumerator() * second.getDenominator();
    int n2 = second.getNumerator() * getDenominator();
    int d = getDenominator() * second.getDenominator();
    return Fraction(n1/n2, d);
}

bool Fraction::operator<(Fraction &second)
{
if(numerator < second.numerator)
{
    return true;
}
else if(denominator < second.denominator)
{
    return true;
}else
{
    return false;
}

}
```

I wonder how should I amend this so that I can overload the operator <, == ? I need a boolean method type that's what I knew but I have no idea to compare. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried...

Comment: If you search for the proper name of what you are trying to do (it's "override" or "overload", not "overwrite") you should see plenty of examples.

Comment: In addition to what @dasblinkenlight said, you can even check wikipedia...

Comment: Hint: make a free function `bool operator== (const Fraction &lhs, const Fraction &rhs)`. Make it a `friend` if you have to.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I don't know about you, but I only accept "override" in the context of virtual functions.

Comment: @chris (metaoff: I always thought "overload" was to be used only for operators and non-member functions, and "override" for [non-operator] member functions.)

Comment: @chris The way I've heard it is "overload" is having more than one function with the same name, and which one is called depends on the types given as parameters, and "override" is when a subclass replaces its superclass's implementation of a function with its own.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13325937/2436175

Comment: @EricFinn, Exactly what I think of it as, though it's still possible to replace the base class's implementation when it's not virtual, but then it becomes hiding, not either of these.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Note: My original answer was not perfect and deal with a number of assumption, mostly that denominator won't be zero, which could be enforced through the class member setter. The setter could also be used to enforce the denominator to be positive (by pushing the sign to the numerator). Once the denominators are forced to be strictly greater than zero, `operator<` can be elegantly written as (see [johnchen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612557/2436175), in which `b * d > 0`):

```
bool Fraction::operator<(const Fraction &second) const
{ 
    return getNumerator() * second.getDenominator() <  second.getNumerator() * getDenominator();
}
```

Here the only remaining risk is in overflow, one could force the data type used in this computation to be `int64_t` to eliminate this risk if the used data type for numerator and denominator is `int32_t` or less.

**Original (low quality) accepted answer:**

```
bool Fraction::operator<(const Fraction &second) const
{ 
    return (float(getNumerator() ) / getDenominator() <  float(second.getNumerator() ) / second.getDenominator() )
}
```

In fact, you should probably have a const method `getFloatingValue`, which returns `float(getNumerator() ) / getDenominator()`: that would simplify writing other comparison functions.

Comment: Perhaps degrading to floating-point numbers is not the best idea when working with exact values.

Comment: To OP: @Gwen this won't work properly for numbers that cannot be represented exactly using a `float`. Sometimes you will get surprising results. This is a dirty solution.

Comment: @H2CO3 I thought the same for a moment, and deleted my answer, but then I had a doubt on how negative numerator or denominator will be treated when using method proposed in the other answers... I have upvoted what is the right answer in my opinion.

Comment: @H2CO3 You mean johnchen's answer?

Comment: Nothing. I mean, floating point hackage is what I don't like.

Answer (score 4):

> I have no idea to compare

Using the fact that

```
(a / b) < (c / d) ←→ (a * d) < (c * b) if b * d > 0
(a / b) < (c / d) ←→ (a * d) > (c * b) if b * d < 0
```

(assuming that no overflow happened)

Comment: @Gwen Sorry, but I mistyped some &lt; and &gt;. See my edit or you'll fail your math exam.

Comment: @Gwen This looks to me as the one and only correct and complete answer. For the C++ implementation you can get inspired by the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple. (A piece of advice: use const references if operators don't modify the objects...)

```
bool Fraction::operator<(const Fraction &that) const
{
    unsigned long long num1 = this->num * that.denom;
    unsigned long long num2 = that.num * this->denom;
    return num1 < num2;
}

bool Fraction::operator==(const Fraction &that) const
{
    // I'm too lazy to do more maths, so I cheat
    return !(*this < that || that < *this);
}
```

Note that this doesn't deal with signed numbers (obviously), that's left to you as an exercise.

Comment: What if `that.denom` is negative and `this->denom` is not?

Comment: I would add const to the method itself, and maybe I would use a long to store num1 and num2

Comment: @johnchen902 Then I rewrite my code using `unsigned int` and the you won't be able to ask such a question :P

Comment: @H2CO3 OP is using `int`. If either of denominator is negative, your code won't work.

Comment: @johnchen902 Yes, I am still aware of that. How about he makes an effort rewriting it using the basic idea I've given here so that it works? I won't just do the homework for people for free, no way.

Comment: @H2CO3 *...using the basic idea I've given here...* I don't think OP is good at math and can get the idea in your code.

Comment: @johnchen902 Feel free to do his homework for him. Write an answer and I will upvote it. (Oh, and if someone wants to do programming, one day eventually he **has to** become good at math, it's inevitable.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't mean to do his homework. I've already wrote one even before you answer.

Comment: @johnchen902 Oh I see! You really did.

Comment: @Antonio Done. After that, let's clean up our comments.

Comment: @H2CO3 No reason to downvote, but I wouldn't call "simple" handling the signedness of numerators and denominators, quite of a brain teaser in fact!